# In React Native - How to move View element in parallely while ScrollView scrolls

Tags: animation, scrollview, react-native, dom-manipulation

I'm developing a `TimeLine` component. There are `Views` list inside horizontal `ScrollView` that represents half an hour blocks. And I have a Component called `TimeRangeSelector`, which I use to select a range of time in `TimeLine` `ScrollView`. So while I scroll the `ScrollView` I need to move the `TimeRangeSelector` in parallel without any lag. Below is the `TimeLine` component. You can see the 30mins blocks are filled inside `ScrollView`. The yellow color one is the `TimeRangeSelector` which is a Animated.View. And the left position of the `TimeRangeSelector` is set using the scroll position. Each time `ScrollView` moves im setting the state as below.

```
<ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      onScroll={this.onScrollFunc}
    >
    {timelineElements}
</ScrollView>

onScrollFunc = (event, gesture) => {
  this.setState({
    contentOffsetX: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,
    scrollStopped: false
  });
};
```

And Im passing the scrollBarPosition as props to the TimeRangeSelector and setting its left position style as shown in below code

```
<TimeRangeSelector
      scrollBarPosition={this.state.contentOffsetX}
    />

let styles= [
  {
    position: "absolute",
    left: this.props.scrollBarPosition,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 1,
    width: this.state.selectionWidth,
    height: 100
  }
];
```

But the issue is when I scroll the `ScrollView` the `TimeRangeSelector` moves with it, but it has a delay.. when I scroll faster the distance between where it should be and where it is, is becoming high. Can anyone give me some ideas according to your knowledge.

My assumption: According to my understanding, I think the lag is because of it takes several instances to reach the `setState` in and set the `ScrollBarPosition` as below steps.

1. `ScrollView` moved 1 frame.
2. `ScrollView` fires the `onScroll` function and emmits the event with new x point.
3. Then in the `onScroll` function it sets the State.

As I understand it takes some time to happen all these steps from JavaScript thread all the way to Native Thread and come back to JS thread again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like `const onScroll = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: animatedValue } } }], { useNativeDriver: true });` with `const animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)`. This way the animation is only done on the native level without going back and forth through the JS thread.

This animated value can only be used effectively with opacity and transform style properties, but it should help you with your problem.

[You can read more about this, in this awesome article.](https://medium.com/xebia/linking-animations-to-scroll-position-in-react-native-5c55995f5a6e)

Comment: I have read this thing somewhere. But i dont know the exact way to implement this. How can i get the exact position of the scrollView of we write Animated.event in this. And is the delay causes be of the setState cycle? Because anyways i need to set the scroll position of scrolling in state, then only i can run the render in order to pass the scroll position to the child (TimeRangeSelector)

Comment: The position is encapsulated in the event, log it in a non-use-native-driver mode and see. The delay is caused by setState and going forth and back from native to JS code.

Comment: Yes must be that. What can you suggest me in this? @Daniel Schmidt

Comment: Without the setState there's no way to call the child component. And i dont understand how can i get the current position within this code " const onScroll = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: animatedValue } } }], { useNativeDriver: true }); "

Comment: @sham999 does it is completed and is it available on github